# Angular http GET request No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: json, xml, angular, api, cors

I'm currently building an application using Angular and Firebase (Firestore).

How can I retrieve the data located here http://maps.huge.info/zipv0.pl?ZIP=32750 and convert it from xml to json?  This is my current get request but it's returning "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".  What am I doing wrong?

```
getZipData() {
  return this.http.get(`http://maps.huge.info/zipv0.pl?ZIP=19382`);
}
```

Comment: What are you using to serve your application?  Most likely you will either need to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers on your server or proxy the API from your local environment. This is a CORS issue and is actually being blocked by the browser's security.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific.  I'm using Google Firebase (Firestore) as my backend

Comment: I'm currently running my application locally.  How can I add CORS in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your firebase config you can specify the following, found in the [config options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config) and that should resolve your issue.

`"headers": [ {
  "source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
  "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "value" : "*"
  } ]
}]`

If you're using the angular-cli and running locally you can use the proxy config and proxy the URL while developing.  https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/

Comment: Does the fact that  http://maps.huge.info/zipv0.pl?ZIP=32750 is an external api which I have no control over change any of this?  How does changing my firebase config help in this situation?

Comment: the firebase config is what your application is served from and dictates the security of your application. That security setting is what decides whether or not you can call API's outside of your domain.  The error is because you're calling an API outside of your domain and protocol. The angular cli proxy config allows you to proxy the api call so it appears to be local (you would change the url in your service to a relative path)

Comment: Okay great thank you.  The owner of maps.huge.info got back to me and said the data is not available for public use so I'm going to have to go in another direction unfortunately.